# Spring : method-not-allowed returns error code 403 (Forbidden) instead of 405

Tags: spring, rest, spring-boot, oauth-2.0, spring-profiles

I'm creating a REST API in Spring that needs to act as a ResouceServer in an Oauth2 client-credential flow. I'm trying to deactivate the need for client-credential during developement and testing so I have created two profiles : 'local' and 'cloud'. Here are the security configuration of each profile.

**cloud**:

```
@Configuration
@EnableResourceServer
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true, proxyTargetClass = true)
@Profile("cloud")
public class CloudSecurityConfiguration extends ResourceServerConfigurerAdapter {

  @Autowired
  private MyEntryPoint myEntryPoint;

  @Override
  public void configure(ResourceServerSecurityConfigurer resources) throws Exception {
    resources.resourceId("res-id");          
    resources.authenticationEntryPoint(myEntryPoint);
  }

  @Override
  public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
      http
              .authorizeRequests()
              .antMatchers("/").permitAll()
              .antMatchers("/.../**").fullyAuthenticated();
  }

}
```

-

```
@Component
@Profile("cloud")
public class MyEntryPoint implements AuthenticationEntryPoint {

  @Autowired
  private HandlerExceptionResolver handlerExceptionResolver;

  @Override
  public void commence(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response,
                     AuthenticationException authException) throws IOException, ServletException {
      handlerExceptionResolver.resolveException(request, response, null, authException);
  }
}
```

**local** :

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@Profile("local")
@Order(Ordered.HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE)
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true, proxyTargetClass = true)
public class LocalSecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
  @Override
  public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
      http.authorizeRequests().anyRequest().permitAll();
  }
}
```

(`@EnableWebSecurity` is used in the local profile instead of `@EnableResourceServer` because it solved a weird problem that if a token was present in the header (even if not needed), every end point in local profile would always return an error response `Invalid access token`)

Now the problem is : only GET method are supported by the API and I have to follow a strict specification saying that it should return a 405 error code when a request with another method, like POST, is sent to the server. With the security layer, it works fine with a `@ControllerAdvice` class that extends `ResponseEntityExceptionHandler`, but when I try to remove the security layer by switching to the "local" profile, in my tests I receive a 403-Forbidden error instead of a 405.

Here is my `ResponseEntityExceptionHandler` :

```
@ControllerAdvice
public class MyErrorHandler extends ResponseEntityExceptionHandler {    

  @ExceptionHandler
  @ResponseBody
  @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST)
  protected ErrorModel handleAllExceptions(ConstraintViolationException e, ServletWebRequest request) {
      return exceptionMapping(e, request, HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST, TypeEnum.V);
  }

  @ExceptionHandler
  @ResponseBody
  @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.UNAUTHORIZED)
  protected ErrorModel handleAllExceptions(AuthenticationException e, ServletWebRequest request) {      
      return exceptionMapping(e, request, HttpStatus.UNAUTHORIZED, TypeEnum.S);
  }

  @ExceptionHandler
  @ResponseBody
  @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.FORBIDDEN)
  protected ErrorModel handleAllExceptions(AccessDeniedException e, ServletWebRequest request) {        
      return exceptionMapping(e, request, HttpStatus.FORBIDDEN, TypeEnum.S);
  } 

  @ExceptionHandler
  @ResponseBody
  @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR)
  protected ErrorModel handleAllExceptions(Exception  e, ServletWebRequest request) {       
      return exceptionMapping(e, request, HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR, TypeEnum.S);
}

  @Override
  protected ResponseEntity<Object> handleHttpRequestMethodNotSupported(HttpRequestMethodNotSupportedException ex,
        HttpHeaders headers, HttpStatus status, WebRequest request) {

      ErrorModel error = exceptionMapping(ex, (ServletWebRequest) request, status, TypeEnum.S);
      return new ResponseEntity<>(error, headers, status);
  }

  private ErrorModel exceptionMapping(Exception e, ServletWebRequest request, HttpStatus status, TypeEnum type) {
    /* build and returns the error view */
  }
}
```

Ex (with 'local' profile) :

`POST http://localhost:8080/.../my-end-point`

response : `status 403`

```
{
   "timestamp": "2019-05-30T15:44:36.021-0400",
   "status": 403,
   "error": "Forbidden",
   "message": " Forbidden",
   "path": "/.../my-end-point"
}
```

> this response has the WRONG format and status code!

Expected : response with `status: 405`, formatted according to the ErrorModel class.

Ex (with 'cloud' profile) :

`POST http://localhost:8080/.../my-end-point`

response : `status 405`

```
{
  "status": 405,
  "errors": [
    {
      "exception": "class org.springframework.web.HttpRequestMethodNotSupportedException",
      "systemId": "91224",
      "code": null,
      "systemName": "sys-name",
      "meta": null,
      "detail": "Request method 'POST' not supported",
      "time": "2019-05-30T15:49:10.021",
      "type": "S",
      "message": null,
      "url": "http://localhost:8080/.../my-end-point"
    }
  ]
}
```

> this response has the right format and status code. It is what is expected and required !

How can I make sure that a POST (or any method other than GET) to the url returns a 405 error when in the local profile ? Again, I want to stress that when the app is run in the 'cloud' profile, everything works as expected.

Comment: I would also accept a solution that solves the reason that forced me to use `@EnableWebSecurity` instead of `@EnableResourceServer`, i.e. not return a `InvalidTokenError` systematically when a token is put in the request headers while in local profile.